# r sequence problem - max number of changes in a given sequence

Tags: r

Can somebody help me understand a CS problem.

The problem is the `New York Time Rollercoaster problem`.

I have a queue:

```
queue <- seq(from = 1, to = 5)
 1 2 3 4 5
```

A person can bribe another person who is ahead of them in the queue but by only a maximum of 2 times. Thus a queue sequence might look like:

```
Ride: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5  # Original queue
Ride: 1, 2, 3, 5, 4  # 5 bribes number 4
Ride: 1, 2, 5, 3, 4  # 5 bribes number 3 and thus runs out of bribes and cannot move further (it does not state in the problem if 3 can "re-bribe" 5 so I assume they cannot).
Ride: 2, 1, 5, 3, 4  # 2 bribes number 1
```

So given the input `c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` what are the minimum number of `swaps` it would take to get to the final output which would be `c(2, 1, 5, 3, 4)`.

Python code from [here](https://www.martinkysel.com/hackerrank-new-year-chaos-solution/):

```
def minimumBribes(q):
    moves = 0
    for pos, val in enumerate(q):
        if (val-1) - pos > 2:
            return "Too chaotic"
        for j in xrange(max(0,val-2), pos):
            if q[j] > val:
                moves+=1
    return moves
```

I am trying to re-create this in R and understand the solution.

Comment: I don't think `how many swaps` is specific enough. Maybe `minimum swaps` is needed? Interesting question+1

Comment: Yes, my apologies, its minimum swaps needed. edited.

Comment: It is not clear in the original post here: https://www.martinkysel.com/hackerrank-new-year-chaos-solution/  so I assume not. I make the assumption that once the person takes their bribe its not worth their while to "re-bribe" their way back into position since they have a higher utility now with the bribe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way I think -

```
minimumBribes <- function(final_q) {
  change <- final_q - seq_along(final_q)
  if(any(change > 2)) return("Too chaotic!")
  sum(change[change > 0])
}

minimumBribes(q = c(2, 1, 5, 3, 4))
[1] 3
```

**Explanation -**

```
initial_q <- 1:5
final_q <- c(2, 1, 5, 3, 4)

# calculate change in position; +ve is gain and -ve is loss
change <- final_q - initial_q

[1]  1 -1  2 -1 -1
# it is clear that if some gained x posn combined then other(s) lost x posn combined
# i.e. sum of posn gains and losses will always be 0

# therefore, to get min total swaps, simply add either gains or losses
# which in a way implies the most direct path from initial_q to final_q
sum(change[change > 0])

[1] 3
```

Comment: It's great. You may wanna post it here: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/new-year-chaos/problem ... p.s. I'd take out the comments and post them as text; your solution is actually very short (and smart) but at first look it doesn't seem so.

Comment: @M-- thanks for the link. I am looking into it. Having trouble with understanding the code format requirement.

Comment: It should be a function getting only the final qeuee, assuming input to be sorted, and should return minimum bribes number.